# Reduce heat output of unused laptop dGPU within Windows

Tags: windows, laptop, graphics-card, gpu, device-manager

I have an nVidia GTX 1650 Ti Max-Q built into my laptop, which I regularly use for rendering and ML-workloads. While I am in lectures at university or using it "in the field" I want to maximise battery life. So I changed a couple of settings in Windows and adjusted my fan curves, which already helped a lot.

Next step: I want to disable my dGPU which is soldered onto my mainboard, so it doesn't generate any heat, while it is not needed. My system runs off of the iGPU on the CPU and I just disabled the GTX 1660 Ti in the device menu of Windows. Though the device still seems to consume a bunch of power, less than before but it's still running.

Is there a way to turn it off entirely until the next restart/change of settings?

Comment: In many laptops the output of the GPU goes through the integrated one, so this isn't possible. What is your laptop?

Comment: @harrymc it's an HP Spectre x360 15-eb0000

Comment: Have you looked to see if the BIOS has such an option?

Comment: I already checked. Sadly it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the
[schematics of the HP Spectre X360 13-4000](https://www.laptopschematic.com/hp-spectre-x360-13-4000-13t-4100-13-4103dx-day0ddmbae0-schematic-boardview/),
and especially this schema :

[image]

As far as I can see, all paths to the DisplayPort (DP) lines start from
the SKYLAKE U Processor, meaning that graphical content  passes
through the discrete GPU.

My conclusion is that it's impossible to turn off the discrete GPU
without losing all graphics output.